# using ofstream to write down a 2-D vector in cython

Tags: c++, vector, formatting, cython, ofstream

I have written a `class` in **cython**, which uses the `vector` in **c++** to create a two-dimensional array. My current issue is that, I would like to `write` and `read` the content of my *array*/*matrix* into and from a *text file*. I'd like to have each row of the matrix be written in the same line. I am also wondering how I can give each written value a `format`?

**matrix.pyx**

```
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
import cython
import numpy as np
import ctypes
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython                                               
from libcpp.string cimport string    
cdef extern from "<iostream>" namespace "std" nogil:
     cdef cppclass ostream:
          ostream& write(const char*, int) except +
     cdef cppclass istream:
          istream& read(const char*, int) except +
     cdef cppclass ifstream(istream):
          ifstream(const char *) except +              
cdef extern from "<fstream>" namespace "std" nogil:         
     cdef cppclass filebuf:
          pass            
     cdef cppclass fstream:
          void close()
          bint is_open()
          void open(const char*, openmode)
          void open(const char&, openmode)
          filebuf* rdbuf() const
          filebuf* rdbuf(filebuf* sb)              
     cdef cppclass ofstream(ostream):
          ofstream(const char*) except +
          ofstream(const char*, openmode) except+
     cdef cppclass ifstream(istream):
          ifstream(const char*) except +
          ifstream(const char*, openmode) except+              
cdef extern from "<iostream>" namespace "std::ios_base" nogil:
    cdef cppclass openmode:
        pass
    cdef open_mode binary    
cdef extern from "<iterator>" namespace "std" nogil:
     cdef cppclass ostream_iterator[T,charT,traits](iterator[output_iterator_tag, void, void, void, void]):
          basic_ostream[charT,traits]* out_stream
          ctypedef charT char_type
          ctypedef traits traits_type
          ctypedef basic_ostream[charT,traits] ostream_type
          ostream_iterator (ostream_type& )
          ostream_iterator (ostream_type& , const charT* )

cdef class Matrix:
     def __cinit__(self, int rows=0, int columns=0):
         self._rows=rows
         self._columns=columns
         self.matrix=new vector[double]()
         self.matrix.resize(rows*columns)
     def __dealloc__(self):
         del self.matrix

     @cython.boundscheck(False)
     @cython.wraparound(False)
     cpdef double getVal(self, int r, int c):
           return self.matrix[0][r*self._columns+c]

     @cython.boundscheck(False)
     @cython.wraparound(False)
     cpdef void setVal(self, int r, int c, double v): 
           self.matrix[0][r*self._columns+c] = v

     @cython.boundscheck(False)
     @cython.wraparound(False)
     cpdef void _write(self, char *filename):

           cdef ofstream* outputter
           outputter = new ofstream(filename, binary)
           cdef int j
           cdef ostream_iterator[double] os(outputter," ")
           cdef ostream_iterator[double] oi(outputter,"\n")
           for j from 0 <= j < self._rows:
               copy(self.matrix.begin()+ j*self._columns,self.matrix.begin()+ (j+1)*self._columns,os)
               copy(self.matrix.begin(),self.matrix.begin(),oi)
```

**matrix.pxd**

```
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
cdef class Matrix:
     cdef vector[double] *matrix   
     cdef int _rows
     cdef int _columns
     cpdef double getVal(self, int r, int c)

     cpdef void setVal(self, int r, int c, double v)
     cpdef void _write(self, char *filename)
```

The error message is:

```
           cdef ofstream out1(filename)
           cdef int j
           cdef ostream_iterator[double] os(out1," ")
                                                ^
------------------------------------------------------------

matrix.pyx:: Expected an identifier, found 'BEGIN_STRING'

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

           cdef ofstream out1(filename)
           cdef int j
           cdef ostream_iterator[double] os(out1," ")
                                                 ^
------------------------------------------------------------

matrix.pyx:: Expected ')', found 'CHARS'
```

Any suggestion for making this code work will be appreciated.

**Update:**

Based on @DavidW answer, I wrote the following function in order to read a file into the `matrix` object.

```
from libcpp.string cimport string
cdef extern from "<sstream>" namespace "std" nogil:
  cdef cppclass istringstream(istream):
    istringstream() except +
    istringstream(const string&) except +
    void str(const string&)

cdef class Matrix:
     def __cinit__(self, size_t rows=0, size_t columns=0):
         self._rows=rows
         self._columns=columns
         self.matrix=new vector[double]()
         self.matrix.resize(rows*columns)   


     cpdef void _read(self, str filename):
           cdef ifstream* infile = new ifstream(filename)
           cdef string line
           cdef size_t i = 0
           cdef size_t columns = 0
           while (getline(infile[0], line, '\n')):
                 istringstream iss(line)                  
                 self.matrix.insert(self.matrix.begin()+i*columns,istream_iterator[double](line),istream_iterator[double]())
                 if (i==0):
                    columns= self.matrix.size()
           del infile
           return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your main issues are that `ofstream` and `ostream_iterator` either can't be default constructed (constructed with no arguments) or assigned, and thus you can't use them stack allocated in Cython (i.e. you need to allocate them with `new`).

I've constructed a very simple example to show how to do this. I've tried to simplify the C++ declarations as much as possible by ignoring unnecessary template parameters (where the defaults are right) and only including the functions you actually use.

I've allocated the `ofstream` as a pointer with `new` and the `ostream_iterator` as a temporary that I pass straight into `copy`. It would also be possible to allocate the `ostream_iterator` as a pointer, although that seems unnecessary.

```
#distutils: language=c++

from libcpp.vector cimport vector

cdef extern from "<ostream>" namespace "std":       
    cdef cppclass ostream:
        ostream& put(char c) # just to write the newlines
cdef extern from "<istream>" namespace "sts":
    cdef cppclass istream:
        pass

cdef extern from "<fstream>" namespace "std":
    cdef cppclass ofstream(ostream):
        ofstream(const char*)
    cdef cppclass ifstream(istream):
        ifstream(const char*)

cdef extern from "<iterator>" namespace "std":
    cdef cppclass ostream_iterator[T]:
        ostream_iterator(ostream&, const char*)
    cdef cppclass istream_iterator[T]:
        istream_iterator(istream&)
        istream_iterator()

cdef extern from "<algorithm>" namespace "std":
    OutputIterator copy[InputIterator,OutputIterator](InputIterator, InputIterator, OutputIterator)

def test_func_write(l):
    "Takes a list/tuple, converts it to a vector
    and then prints that twice"
    cdef vector[int] v = l
    cdef ofstream* fout = new ofstream("output.txt");
    try:
        copy(v.begin(),v.end(),ostream_iterator[int](fout[0]," "))
        fout.put("\n")
        copy(v.begin(),v.end(),ostream_iterator[int](fout[0]," "))
        fout.put("\n")
    finally:
        del fout

def test_func_read():
    cdef vector[int] v
    cdef ifstream* fin = new ifstream("output.txt")
    try:
        v.insert(v.end(),istream_iterator[int](fin[0]),istream_iterator[int]())
        return v
    finally:
        del fin
```

I'm writing the newlines directly to `fout` using the `put` function.

Reading is always a little more complicated than writing. We can `insert` directly into the vector, and it'll keep reading  until it reaches the end. Unfortunately it treats newlines and spaces the same (and this is difficult to change in C++ streams) so it's hard to work out the matrix shape as we go. The simplest solution would be to write the file so the first element gives the number of columns. A more complicated approach would be to use [`getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) to get each line as a string, then make an `istringstream` for each line.

---

Controlling formatting *does not really work* for `ostream_iterator`. The `ostream`s have a variety of functions to control the formatting (e.g. `width`, `fill` and `setf`. However, they only apply to the next output then  are reset. Therefore they're pretty useless with an iterator writing multiple outputs. A common solution ([1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/18291/setting-output-width-with-ostream-iterator) [2](http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2008/04/10/output-formatting-with-stdcopy/)) seems to be to write a wrapper class to apply to formatters to each element but this isn't really practical in Cython.

Just in case you want to use the format flags (and write one element at a time) you'd do it like

```
cdef extern from "<ostream>" namespace "std":
    cdef cppclass fmtflags "std::ios_base::fmtflags":
        pass
    fmtflags left "std::ios_base::left"
    fmtflags right "std::ios_base::left"
    # etc...

    cdef cppclass ostream:
        #...
        fmtflags setf(fmtflags)
        int width(int)
        char fill(char)
```

and then you'd just call:

```
fout.width(10)
fout.fill("x")
fout.setf(left)
```

---

For what it's worth, I really don't think trying to write a matrix class using the C++ standard library in Cython is a good idea - you're always going to be fighting with Cython's limited support for C++ templates.

---

*Hopefully final edit:* Your "read" example using `getline` and `istringstream` wasn't far off. Just to list the changes I had to make

```
# istream needs a "bool" operator for you to use it in a while loop.
# You could also use the function "good()"
from libcpp cimport bool
cdef extern from "<istream>" namespace "std":
    cdef cppclass istream:
        bool operator bool()

# You need to declare getline. I'm using the simpler version without
# the delimiter but it doesn't really matter
cdef extern from "<string>" namespace "std":
    istream& getline(istream&, string& s)

# the loop looks like:
while (getline(infile[0], line)):
    self.matrix.insert(self.matrix.end(), # use "end" to insert at the back (this was a mistake in my original example
                       istream_iterator[double](istringstream(line)), # just make the istringstream as a temporary
                       istream_iterator[double]())
    if (i==0):
        columns= self.matrix.size()
    i += 1 # you forgot this
```

Comment: I appreciate for the answer like always! What about reading a file using the same library? Would you explain a bit? Thanks.

Comment: I've edited in reading. Wrapping the C++ is really very similar, however reading is always harder than writing, and C++ iostreams are pretty inflexible so you can't easily tell spaces from newlines

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So does it work if I give **gives the number of columns** and would you make it clear please by giving an example, using `getline` reading and parsing each row and column?

Comment: I tried to implement your explanation of how to read the written file into an empty `matrix` object but I get some errors. I will appreciate if you could point out where I did something wrong. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I will be grateful! :)

Comment: Right - I've edited to show you what you need to change on your reading example. It was pretty close to working but missing a few `cdef extern`s. There's a small mistake in my original answer - you should insert to "end" rather than "begin" (but for an empty vector they're identical so it worked)

Comment: @DawidW Thanks again. Is `istream` coming from a `c++` library? Because when I compile my code based on your answer, I get this error: `from libcpp cimport bool  cdef cppclass istream:
    bool operator bool()
                 ^
------------------------------------------------------------

matrix.pyx:17:18: Syntax error in C variable declaration`

Comment: Yes - it's coming from `cdef extern from "<istream>" namespace "std":`

Comment: Now I get this error:`matrix.cpp:error: ‘class std::basic_istream<char>’ has no member named ‘operator bool’
     __pyx_t_8 = std::getline((__pyx_v_infile[0]), __pyx_v_line).operator bool();
                                                                          ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:42:0,
                 from matrix.cpp:563:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/ios_base.h: In member function ‘std::basic_ios<char>& std::basic_ios<char>::operator=(const std::basic_ios<char>&)’:`

Comment: also these :`/usr/include/c++/5/streambuf:807:7: error: ‘std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>::operator=(const std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’ is private
       operator=(const basic_streambuf&);
       ^
In file included from matrix.cpp:575:0:
/usr/include/c++/5/sstream:65:11: error: within this context
     class basic_stringbuf : public basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>
           ^
`

Comment: `operator bool` is a C++11 addition. Either tell it to use C++11, or alternatively use the function `getline(...).good()`. I'm not sure about the `operator=` since I can't really see where it's happening. I suspect it'll go away if you can set it to use C++11

Comment: I changed the compiler to `extra_compile_args = ['-std=c++11']` and it works! I appreciate for being patient and kindly answering my question.